# Getting Mapped column names in knowledge module

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I need to get the the specified mapped column names only, I tried using `<%=odiRef.getColList("", "[CX_COL_NAME]",",", "","")%>` and `<%=odiRef.getColList("", "[EXPRESSION]", "~~", "")%>` but both returns all the column names instead of the particular mapped column.

Even after mapping just one column to another, what I am receiving is all the fields mapped against another.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you use the UD1 ... UD10 flags on the mapped column to identify it?

Comment: I haven't used UD1 flags, how can I use it? Any example or link to see that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `odiRef.getTargetColList()`

According to ODI Documentation

> Use to return information about the active attributes of the target
> table of a mapping. Active attributes are those having an active
> mapping.

It shoould bring the list of attributes that have mapping only. But you won't get the epression. You can see detailed doc in

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/odi/ODIKD/odiref_reference.htm#ODIKD1300